# MS Access Subform not displaying existing data

Tags: ms-access, subform

I have a sub-form that is not displaying data when I change records on the main form. Both forms are based on tables. I've been changing records on the main form via a combo box--works great, displays everything on the main form that it should. The subform is blank--I can enter in new data, but it is not displaying any existing data related to the record displayed on the main form. I need the existing related data to display so that it can be updated (it's a rental inventory, so to mark a checkbox that an item was returned).

Master & child fields are identical and related as follows in a 1:many relationship.
master (tbl Rental Details) = RentalID (PK, autonumber)
child (tbl Rental Inventory) = RentalID (FK, number)
Data entry: No on both.
Filter on Load: No on both.

Access crashed on me twice, and then started giving me some fun errors (return without gosub) on this form so I ran a decompile and compact & repair. The errors are gone, but it started doing this and I'm stumped.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying that it used to work, and now it doesn't? Or it never worked as intended?

Comment: @HackSlash used to work and now doesn't.  It was working and then Access crashed.  When I restarted, I got the gosub error, ran decompile and compact/repair and now it doesn't work.

Comment: If your DB is corrupt it is unlikely there will be a programming related answer. Can you restore a backup from before the crash? (Your front-end should be split from your backend so you can swap out the front end without losing the data in the backend.)

Comment: @HackSlash I'm still building it, so it's not split yet and only contains some test/dummy data.  I guess I can go back to my back-up from yesterday and re-do the subform (it didn't exist until today) and see if it works.

Comment: That would be preferable to developing a new application based on a corrupted file.

Comment: I recommend using this plugin to version control your front end: https://github.com/joyfullservice/msaccess-vcs-integration This allows you to rebuild the project from text files. I have used this to recover from a corrupted state.